# gcc cannot find standard libraries on mac (when installing python packages from requirements)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, gcc

I am having an issue due to my gcc missing standard libraries.

```
    copying blpapi/schema.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/blpapi
    running build_ext
    building 'blpapi._internals' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/blpapi
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/envs/invtools/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/envs/invtools/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/lib/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/include -I/anaconda3/envs/invtools/include/python3.7m -c blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/blpapi/internals_wrap.o
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx:3101:10: fatal error: 'stdexcept' file not found
    #include <stdexcept>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I had a different issue initially. It was something about cannot find type `uint8_t`. And [someone](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/653) suggested to delete files in: `/usr/local/include/`. And that causes the above now. It is because there are no standard libraries now. I installed this `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` and now I have standard lib in `/usr/include`. Which I copied to `/usr/local/indclude/` to no avail. `brew link gcc` tells me:

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0
To relink: brew unlink gcc && brew link gcc
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem is the use of the `gcc` front-end program. It will not add options for the actual compiler that is needed for C++. For that the `g++` front-end program needs to be used.

Comment: how would you force it to use `g++`? I have done `conda install -y gcc` and that solved the issue... No idea why

Comment: Reading your output a little closer, it seems that the `gcc` used is the Clang alias when the real GCC is not installed. That's probably why it worked when you installed the *real* GCC.